# bxslider carousel code

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-selectors, bxslider

i am trying to implement the slider from this site

http://bxslider.com/

i used the exact procedure what they said but still my code is not working
can you guys tell me how to fix it

i am providing my fiddle code blow

http://jsfiddle.net/v3efb/3/

http://jsfiddle.net/v3efb/3/embedded/result/

providing my code below

```
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="http://maxcdn.webappers.com/img/2009/01/jquery-carousel.png" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://maxcdn.webappers.com/img/2009/01/jquery-carousel.png" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://maxcdn.webappers.com/img/2009/01/jquery-carousel.png" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://maxcdn.webappers.com/img/2009/01/jquery-carousel.png" /></li>
</ul>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link href="/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});


</script>
```

Comment: user1914176, did my Answer solve your question?

Answer (score 0):

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/v3efb/4/)

In your markup, you are using ***relative paths*** to `jquery.min.js`, `bxslider.min.js` and `bxslider.css` files.

That means those files are locally available in their respective subfolders.

However, jsFiddle does not know the complete URL path, aka the ***absolute path***, to those files.

Change the paths so they are a complete URL.

**Tip:** In jsFiddle, you can import `.js` and `.css` files as assets using the ***Add Resources*** panel on left side.