# Add Parallax effect to Carousel Banner so images and text move at different speeds

Tags: jquery, css, banner, parallax

I have the carousel effect working, but I don't know how to make the text and images move at different speeds as shown in this banner for IBM:

http://www.ibm.com/us/en/

Here's my jQuery:

```
$.fn.zinCarousel = function(settings) {
    var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.zinCarousel.defaultSettings, settings || {});
    return this.each(function() {
        var o = $.extend(true, {}, settings),
            $elem = $(this),
            caro = new Carousel(o, $elem);
        caro.init();
    });
};
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9Dr7T/35/show) (Remove `/show/` from URL to access edit page).

Comment: The IBM Carousal code you mentioned is a [**Parallax**](https://www.google.com/search?q=best+jQuery+parallax) effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an online tutorial and live demo featuring a **Parallax Carousel Banner**.

[**Parallax Content Slider with CSS3 and jQuery**](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/03/15/parallax-content-slider-with-css3-and-jquery/)

Do note the above example is one of many you'll find on the internet, as this one uses `CSS3` for modern browsers.

Direct link to [**DEMO**](http://tympanus.net/Development/ParallaxContentSlider/).

Comment: thanks for your reply...i saw the demo i tried moving image and text separately but could not move it separately....can you tell me how to movie it separetely....i wanted left half side to move separately followed by right half for one slide

Comment: According to that specific tutorial, you can change the value of the `bgincrement` value. It states: `increments the background position (parallax effect) when sliding`. But you can always use jQuery selectors to add extra animation routines as well. I do recommend that you determine which of the many [**jQuery Parallax Carousel**](https://www.google.com/search?q=jQuery+Parallax+Carousel) plugins would work best in your webpage.

Comment: I looked at that IBM Parallax Banner and it's custom made from the ground up. The best solution is to review what Parallax plugins have the best options for your needs, and then work with that jQuery framework to animate both the text and images separately.

Comment: @attronics: can you tell me what value to change to work exactly like ibm carousal effects

Comment: There will be nothing, I repeat, nothing exactly like IBM Parallax Banner because that is 1 of a kind custom made. However, [**this online demo**](http://www.parallaxslider.com/classic.php) shows a Parallax Plugin with the features you require and looks very similar to IBM version, except that it is USA $10 but perhaps there are free ones on the internet that can be adapted (use the word 'free' in your search).

Comment: Side Note: The IBM website which includes the Parallax Banner does not use jQuery, it uses [**Dojo Framework**](http://dojotoolkit.org/) for everything.

Comment: @attronics: it woud be great if u tell me what to modify in css or jquery code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21604/discussion-between-user1914176-and-arttronics)

Comment: What to modify depends on your webpage layout, how the jQuery script is modified, your HTML markup, your CSS markup, and your animation Parallax goals. That in and of itself is beyond the scope of your question.